# Align Text below Image center correctly

Tags: android

```
   Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter){
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 120.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
            content = {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.logo),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                )
                Text("Medicine")
            }
        )
    }
```

The `Text()` component, appears above the logo, how to bring it down below? Aligning it center below with some padding.

EDIT: I tried this,

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center).padding(0.dp),text = "Medicine")
```

But, the text appear way down.

Comment: Box is meant to work that way. Put the logo and image in a column instead of the box?

Comment: logo and *text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to change the inner Box to Column.
[There are examples of alignment in column](https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-jetpack-compose-column/)

Comment: **Why** would you do that?

Comment: Column is just created to put things one below another. Alignment in box works in different way.